# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'defined' (T_STRING) in /components/com_spidercatalog/views/spidercatalog/tmpl/default_cube3.php on line 1

Tags: php, joomla

What problem to my code, it showing

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'defined' (T_STRING) in /home/jackgohc/public_html/fidaccess.com/components/com_spidercatalog/views/spidercatalog/tmpl/default_cube3.php on line 1

Following is my code

```
    <?php
    /**
     * @package Spider Catalog
     * @author Web-Dorado
     * @copyright (C) 2012 Web-Dorado. All rights reserved.
     * @license GNU/GPLv3 http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html
     **/

    defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
    $prod_iterator = 0;

    $rows = $this->rows;
    $option = $this->option;
    $params =  $this->params;
    $page_num = $this->page_num;
    $prod_count = $this->prod_count;
    $prod_in_page = $this->prod_in_page;
    $ratings = $this->ratings;
    $voted = $this->voted;
    $categories = $this->categories;
    $category_list = $this->category_list;
    $params1 =  $this->params1;
    $cat_rows=$this->cat_rows;
    $cat_id=$this->cat_id;
    $child_ids=$this->child_ids;
    $categor = $this->categor;
    $par=$this->par;
    $subcat_id=$this->subcat_id;
    $prod_name=$this->prod_name;
    $input=JFactory::getApplication()->input;
    ?>

      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <script>
    /* jQuery Lightbox Version 0.5 - 11/29/2007 @author Warren Krewenki */
    (function(a){a.fn.lightbox=function(h){var s=a.extend({},a.fn.lightbox.defaults,h);return this.each(function(){a(this).click(function(){e();n(this);return false;});});function e(){a("#overlay").remove();a("#lightbox").remove();s.inprogress=false;if(s.jsonData&&s.jsonData.length>0){var y=s.jsonDataParser?s.jsonDataParser:a.fn.lightbox.parseJsonData;s.imageArray=[];s.imageArray=y(s.jsonData);}var v='<div id="outerImageContainer"><div id="imageContainer"><iframe id="lightboxIframe" /><img id="lightboxImage"><div id="hoverNav"><a href="javascript://" title="'+s.strings.prevLinkTitle+'" id="prevLink"></a><a href="javascript://" id="nextLink" title="'+s.strings.nextLinkTitle+'"></a></div><div id="loading"><a href="javascript://" id="loadingLink"><img src="'+s.fileLoadingImage+'"></a></div></div></div>';var x='<div id="imageDataContainer" class="clearfix"><div id="imageData"><div id="imageDetails"><span id="caption"></span><span id="numberDisplay"></span></div><div id="bottomNav">';if(s.displayHelp){x+='<span id="helpDisplay">'+s.strings.help+"</span>";}x+='<a href="javascript://" id="bottomNavClose" title="'+s.strings.closeTitle+'"><img src="'+s.fileBottomNavCloseImage+'"></a></div></div></div>';var w;if(s.navbarOnTop){w='<div id="overlay"></div><div id="lightbox">'+x+v+"</div>";a("body").append(w);a("#imageDataContainer").addClass("ontop");}else{w='<div id="overlay"></div><div id="lightbox">'+v+x+"</div>";a("body").append(w);}a("#overlay").click(function(){l();}).hide();a("#lightbox").click(function(){l();}).hide();a("#loadingLink").click(function(){l();return false;});a("#bottomNavClose").click(function(){l();return false;});a("#outerImageContainer").width(s.widthCurrent).height(s.heightCurrent);a("#imageDataContainer").width(s.widthCurrent);if(!s.imageClickClose){a("#lightboxImage").click(function(){return false;});a("#hoverNav").click(function(){return false;});}}function u(){var v=new Array(a(document).width(),a(document).height(),a(window).width(),a(window).height());return v;}function g(){var x,v;if(self.pageYOffset){v=self.pageYOffset;x=self.pageXOffset;}else{if(document.documentElement&&document.documentElement.scrollTop){v=document.documentElement.scrollTop;x=document.documentElement.scrollLeft;}else{if(document.body){v=document.body.scrollTop;x=document.body.scrollLeft;}}}var w=new Array(x,v);return w;}function o(x){var w=new Date();var v=null;do{v=new Date();}while(v-w<x);}function n(z){a('select, embed, object[class!="player"]').hide(); var w=u();a("#overlay").hide().css({width:"100%",height:w[1]+"px",opacity:s.overlayOpacity}).fadeIn();imageNum=0;if(!s.jsonData){s.imageArray=[];if(!z.rel||(z.rel=="")){s.imageArray.push(new Array(z.href,s.displayTitle?z.title:""));}else{a("a").each(function(){if(this.href&&(this.rel==z.rel)){s.imageArray.push(new Array(this.href,s.displayTitle?this.title:""));}});}}if(s.imageArray.length>1){for(i=0;i<s.imageArray.length;i++){for(j=s.imageArray.length-1;j>i;j--){if(s.imageArray[i][0]==s.imageArray[j][0]){s.imageArray.splice(j,1);}}}while(s.imageArray[imageNum][0]!=z.href){imageNum++;}}var v=g();var y=v[1]+(w[3]/10);var x=v[0];a("#lightbox").css({top:y+"px",left:x+"px"}).show();if(!s.slideNavBar){a("#imageData").hide();}t(imageNum);}function t(v){if(s.inprogress==false){s.inprogress=true;s.activeImage=v;a("#loading").show();a("#lightboxImage").hide();a("#hoverNav").hide();a("#prevLink").hide();a("#j3Link").hide();if(s.slideNavBar){a("#imageDataContainer").hide();a("#imageData").hide();k();}else{k();}}}function k(){imgPreloader=new Image();imgPreloader.onload=function(){var z=imgPreloader.width;var v=imgPreloader.height;if(s.fitToScreen){var x=u();var y;var w=x[2]-2*s.borderSize;var A=x[3]-200;if(imgPreloader.height>A){z=parseInt((A/imgPreloader.height)*imgPreloader.width);v=A;}else{if(imgPreloader.width>w){v=parseInt((w/imgPreloader.width)*imgPreloader.height);z=w;}}}a("#lightboxImage").attr("src",s.imageArray[s.activeImage][0]).width(z).height(v);m(z,v);};imgPreloader.src=s.imageArray[s.activeImage][0];}function l(){p();a("#lightbox").hide();a("#overlay").fadeOut();a('select, embed, object[class!="player"]').show();}function f(){if(s.loopImages&&s.imageArray.length>1){preloadNextImage=new Image();preloadNextImage.src=s.imageArray[(s.activeImage==(s.imageArray.length-1))?0:s.activeImage+1][0];preloadPrevImage=new Image();preloadPrevImage.src=s.imageArray[(s.activeImage==0)?(s.imageArray.length-1):s.activeImage-1][0];}else{if((s.imageArray.length-1)>s.activeImage){preloadNextImage=new Image();preloadNextImage.src=s.imageArray[s.activeImage+1][0];}if(s.activeImage>0){preloadPrevImage=new Image();preloadPrevImage.src=s.imageArray[s.activeImage-1][0];}}}function m(y,w){s.widthCurrent=a("#outerImageContainer").outerWidth();s.heightCurrent=a("#outerImageContainer").outerHeight();var v=Math.max(350,y+(s.borderSize*2));var x=(w+(s.borderSize*2));s.xScale=(v/s.widthCurrent)*100;s.yScale=(x/s.heightCurrent)*100;wDiff=s.widthCurrent-v;hDiff=s.heightCurrent-x;a("#imageDataContainer").animate({width:v},s.resizeSpeed,"linear");a("#outerImageContainer").animate({width:v},s.resizeSpeed,"linear",function(){a("#outerImageContainer").animate({height:x},s.resizeSpeed,"linear",function(){d();});});if((hDiff==0)&&(wDiff==0)){if(jQuery.browser.msie){o(250);}else{o(100);}}a("#prevLink").height(w);a("#nextLink").height(w);}function d(){a("#loading").hide();a("#lightboxImage").fadeIn("fast");c();f();s.inprogress=false;}function c(){a("#numberDisplay").html("");if(s.imageArray[s.activeImage][1]){a("#caption").html(s.imageArray[s.activeImage][1]).show();}if(s.imageArray.length>1){var w;w=s.strings.image+(s.activeImage+1)+s.strings.of+s.imageArray.length;if(!s.disableNavbarLinks){if((s.activeImage)>0||s.loopImages){w='<a title="'+s.strings.prevLinkTitle+'" href="#" id="prevLinkText">'+s.strings.prevLinkText+"</a>"+w;}if(((s.activeImage+1)<s.imageArray.length)||s.loopImages){w+='<a title="'+s.strings.nextLinkTitle+'" href="#" id="nextLinkText">'+s.strings.nextLinkText+"</a>";}}a("#numberDisplay").html(w).show();}if(s.slideNavBar){a("#imageData").slideDown(s.navBarSlideSpeed);}else{a("#imageData").show();}var v=u();a("#overlay").height(v[1]);q();}function q(){if(s.imageArray.length>1){a("#hoverNav").show();if(s.loopImages){a("#prevLink,#prevLinkText").show().click(function(){t((s.activeImage==0)?(s.imageArray.length-1):s.activeImage-1);return false;});a("#nextLink,#nextLinkText").show().click(function(){t((s.activeImage==(s.imageArray.length-1))?0:s.activeImage+1);return false;});}else{if(s.activeImage!=0){a("#prevLink,#prevLinkText").show().click(function(){t(s.activeImage-1);return false;});}if(s.activeImage!=(s.imageArray.length-1)){a("#nextLink,#nextLinkText").show().click(function(){t(s.activeImage+1);return false;});}}b();}}function r(y){var z=y.data.opts;var v=y.keyCode;var w=27;var x=String.fromCharCode(v).toLowerCase();if((x=="x")||(x=="o")||(x=="c")||(v==w)){l();}else{if((x=="p")||(v==37)){if(z.loopImages){p();t((z.activeImage==0)?(z.imageArray.length-1):z.activeImage-1);}else{if(z.activeImage!=0){p();t(z.activeImage-1);}}}else{if((x=="n")||(v==39)){if(s.loopImages){p();t((z.activeImage==(z.imageArray.length-1))?0:z.activeImage+1);}else{if(z.activeImage!=(z.imageArray.length-1)){p();t(z.activeImage+1);}}}}}}function b(){a(document).bind("keydown",{opts:s},r);}function p(){a(document).unbind("keydown");}};a.fn.lightbox.parseJsonData=function(c){var b=[];a.each(c,function(){b.push(new Array(this.url,this.title));});return b;};a.fn.lightbox.defaults={fileLoadingImage:"<?php echo JURI::root(); ?>components/com_spidercatalog/images/loading.gif",fileBottomNavCloseImage:"<?php echo JURI::root(); ?>components/com_spidercatalog/images/close.png",overlayOpacity:0.8,borderSize:10,imageArray:new Array,activeImage:null,inprogress:false,resizeSpeed:350,widthCurrent:250,heightCurrent:250,xScale:1,yScale:1,displayTitle:true,navbarOnTop:false,slideNavBar:false,navBarSlideSpeed:350,displayHelp:false,strings:{help:" \u2190 / P - previous image\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u2192 / N - next image\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0ESC / X - close image gallery",prevLinkTitle:"previous image",nextLinkTitle:"next image",prevLinkText:"&laquo; Previous",nextLinkText:"Next &raquo;",closeTitle:"close image gallery",image:"Image ",of:" of "},fitToScreen:false,disableNavbarLinks:false,loopImages:false,imageClickClose:true,jsonData:null,jsonDataParser:null};})(jQuery);
    </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/com_spidercatalog/css/lightbox.css" type="text/css" />
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/com_spidercatalog/css/spidercatalog_main.css" type="text/css" />
          <script>
          var select_open_or_hide=0;
          function open_sp_catalog_select(elem) {
              if (document.createEvent) {
                  var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
                  e.initMouseEvent("mousedown", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
                  elem[0].dispatchEvent(e);
              } else if (element.fireEvent) {
                 elem[0].fireEvent("onmousedown");
              }
          }
          jQuery(document).ready(function() {                 
                jQuery('.select-img').click(function() {
                    select_open_or_hide++;
                    if(select_open_or_hide%2==1)
                        open_sp_catalog_select(jQuery('#cat_id'));
                });
            });
          var id=0;




          $(document).ready(function(){


        $("a").click(function(){
        <?php   foreach ($rows as $key=>$row)
      {
      ?>
    $("#productMainDiv a[href$='.jpg#<?php echo $row->id; ?>']").removeAttr("rel");
    <?php   } ?>
    $("#productMainDiv a[href$='.jpg']").removeAttr("rel");

            var lightlast = $(this).attr("href");
            var lastChar = lightlast.substr(lightlast.length - 1);
            id=$(this).attr("href").replace("#","");
            //alert($(this).attr("href"));
            //alert(lastChar);
        $("#productMainDiv a[href$='.jpg#"+lastChar+"']").attr({"rel":"productMainDiv"});

        //alert($("#productMainDiv a[href$='.jpg#"+lastChar+"']").attr({"rel":"productMainDiv"}));
        //$("#productMainDiv a[href$='.jpg#'], #productMainDiv a[href$='.png'], #productMainDiv a[href$='.gif']").attr({"rel":"productMainDiv"});

         });

    <?php   foreach ($rows as $key=>$row)
      {
      ?>

        $("a[href$='.jpg#<?php echo $row->id; ?>'], a[href$='.png#<?php echo $row->id; ?>'], a[href$='.gif#<?php echo $row->id; ?>']").lightbox({fitToScreen:true,loopImages:true,imageClickClose:true,disableNavbarLinks:true});


    <?php   } ?>
    $("a[href$='.jpg'], a[href$='.png'], a[href$='.gif']").lightbox({fitToScreen:true,loopImages:true,imageClickClose:true,disableNavbarLinks:true});
    });


          </script>
    <?php
    if ($params->get('enable_rating')):
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">

    .star-rating                    { background: url(<?php
        echo JURI::root() . '/components/' . $option . '/images/star' . $params->get('rating_star') . '.png';
    ?>) top left repeat-x !important; }

    .star-rating li a:hover         { background: url(<?php
        echo JURI::root() . '/components/' . $option . '/images/star' . $params->get('rating_star') . '.png';
    ?>) left bottom !important; }

    .star-rating li.current-rating  { background: url(<?php
        echo JURI::root() . '/components/' . $option . '/images/star' . $params->get('rating_star') . '.png';
    ?>) left center !important; }

    .star-rating1                   { background: url(<?php
        echo JURI::root() . '/components/' . $option . '/images/star' . $params->get('rating_star') . '.png';
    ?>) top left repeat-x !important; }

    .star-rating1 li.current-rating { background: url(<?php
        echo JURI::root() . '/components/' . $option . '/images/star' . $params->get('rating_star') . '.png';
    ?>) left center !important; }

    </style>

    <?php
    endif;

    if ($params->get('rounded_corners')):
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
    #productMainDiv, .spidercatalogbutton, .spidercataloginput
    {
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    }

    #productMainDiv #prodTitle
    {

    }
    </style>
    <?php
    endif;

    $menu = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu();
    $active = $menu->getActive();  
       if($active){
    $meta_description = $active->params->get('menu-meta_description');
    $meta_keywords = $active->params->get('menu-meta_keywords');

    $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
    if($meta_description)
                $doc->setDescription($meta_description);
    if($meta_keywords)
                $doc->setMetadata('keywords',$meta_keywords);
    }

    $menu = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu();
    $active = $menu->getActive();  
       if($active){
       $menuname = $active->params->get('page_heading');
       if($active->params->get('show_page_heading', 1)==1){      
          echo "<h1>".$menuname."</h1>";
       }
    }


    $session = JFactory::getSession();

    $aa= JRequest::getVar('session_id');

    $pagenumid= JRequest::getVar('page_num');

    ?>
    <script>

    function catt_idd(id)
    { 

        document.getElementById("subcat_id").value=id;

        document.cat_form.submit();
        }

    </script>

    <?php
    $config = JFactory::getConfig();
    //echo $config->get( 'sef' );
    foreach($categor as $chidd){

    if(($input->get('cat_id')>0 or $input->get('subcat_id')>0) and $input->get('cat_id')!=$params1['select_categories'] and $input->get('subcat_id')!=$params1['select_categories'] and $par!=0 and $params1['show_category_details']==1){

    //echo '<a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="catt_idd('.$chidd->parent.')" >'.('Back to Catalog').'</a>';
    echo '<a style="cursor:pointer;" class="subthissubcatback'.$chidd->parent.'" >'.('Back to Catalog').'</a>';
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have closing braces of `if` and `foreach $categor loop`, try this,

```
foreach($categor as $chidd){

    if(($input->get('cat_id')>0 or $input->get('subcat_id')>0) and $input->get('cat_id')!=$params1['select_categories'] and $input->get('subcat_id')!=$params1['select_categories'] and $par!=0 and $params1['show_category_details']==1){

       //echo '<a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="catt_idd('.$chidd->parent.')" >'.('Back to Catalog').'</a>';
       echo '<a style="cursor:pointer;" class="subthissubcatback'.$chidd->parent.'" >'.('Back to Catalog').'</a>';
    } // closing if
} // closing foreach $categor
```